# Tag a photo in facebook post on android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, tags

I have a problem sharing a photo using facebook's APIs on Android sdk.
In the way I share the photo is correctly uploaded, but I can't manage how to tag people.
I tried with my own userID, but in the following way the tag doesn't appear.
I read many thread on this and other forums, but I didn't find any working answer.

I hope you could help me,
this is my code (where 515159228582518 is my userId) :

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

Bitmap bmp = Data.getData().getFinallyCard();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

postParams.putString("message", "Message");
postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);

postParams.putString("place", "166793820034304");
postParams.putStringArray("tags", new String[]{"515159228582518"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't tag people in photos in the same request as the upload. If you have a look at the photos publishing documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#publish) you'll see that there's no "tags" parameter.

What you need to do is use the "id" in the response to the photo upload, and then create another request to /{photo-id}/tags

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo/tags/ for more details.

BTW, you should be able to put both requests into a batch (using the output of the first request as the input to the second request) so you only make one network connection.